# Regular expressions, find matches

Tags: regex

This regular expression gives answer 3 for count.
How can I take only first and second "some" before "hello" ?
Help me, please.

```
string SomeText ="Some some hello some" 
string patternSome = @"some";

RegexOptions RegOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;
Regex newRegex = new Regex(patternSome, RegOptions );

MatchCollection matches = newRegex.Matches(SomeText);
Console.WriteLine("Count of matches {0}", matches.Count);
```

Comment: You might want to include what language this is. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead regex:

```
\b[Ss]ome\b(?=.*hello)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH2sT8/1)

This will match `some` or `Some` only if it is followed by a `hello`.